# Define popup window option in Servlet Controller class

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have defined my edit page in Servlet controller class as

```
private static final String EDIT = "edit.jsp";
```

In controller class based on request parameter edit/delete page is displayed.
If it is edit option I redirect to `edit.jsp`

Is it possible to open `edit.jsp` as popup window that I could define in controller class?

Or is it possible to trigger the following if request parameter is edit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openEdit() {
        window.open('edit.jsp','width=400, height=400');
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks